# Excel SumIF dates in another cell are from previous month

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

I have a table of mortgage loans in Excel. I want to sum the loan amounts(B:B) for loans whose lock dates(D:D) were in the previous month. I am trying to use the "SumIF" function to pull criteria from a different cell as below:

```
=SUMIF(range,"*"&A1&"*",sum_range)
```

But I want to pull a "date between previous month start and previous month end" range. I've used this for another function and it has worked.

```
D:D,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,D:D,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1
```

Now, I am trying to infuse the latter function into the first, something like this, but it is not returning anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
=SUMIF(Data!D:D,"*">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,Data!D:D,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)*",Data!B:B)
```

Comment: That last formula is a `SUMIFS`, right? If not it should be.

Comment: It errors when I try to use SUMIFS instead of SUMIF

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMIFS` when you have multiple criteria, and from your explanation, it seems like you don't need the wildcard `"*"`.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,D:D,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,D:D,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, just had to remove the wildcard! Could you offer some help on a similar function? I have an array of exceptions in Column C. If there is not an exception, a '0' is populated. So I need to Count the number of exceptions there are for any lock that occurred from the previous month (column D). This is what i have now but it is not returning what I need:  =COUNTIFS(C:C,">0"+">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,D:D,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)

Comment: If I understand your description, I think this will do it - `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>"&0,D:D,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,D:D,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)`. Also, please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you - thanks!